# How to check if parameters are null when using positional record constructors and/or init properties?

Tags: c#, .net

I would like check no null parameters are assigned to record fields and let the properties have comments. I have found out the following arrangement does the trick for comments, but I lack ideas to check for null parameters without turning this record into a class.

So, a question: Is it possible to check during runtime that nulls won't be assigned to record fields? If so, how could one do it while still using records?

```
public record Test(string TestString)
{
   /// <summary>
   /// This is one way to get a comment on record properties. Are there others?
   /// </summary>
   public string TestString { get; init; } = TestString;
}
```

The code is also as a gist [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgPgYhgVwDaosVBTABNmTHAWACgyABAJgEYz7SKBmXAJ2wGMB7VgE1wAq2AM4AXABQUaABkEjRAZVGtYAcwCUZAN5lcegPSHcAHmHIwkVgE8AfLoNGBACyjDcr3Fxh4A7hCu4oly4qtiiuBC43BYE4V5snDz8AA6sXMnYrKJQIgB0uACC7IFOmXhcoqWswgD89riG+ib6ZhYQ1nakerjMPTJyYkoqMKq4WiFhANzuMFCi0wC+uAC8A4rKapNkCwxAA).

This is an addition, but maybe helps with the accepted answer and the comment of different code.

It was because the code in the gist did a null check like

```
public record Test(string TestString)
{
   /// <summary>
   /// This is one way to get a comment on record properties. Are there others?
   /// </summary>
   public string TestString { get; init; } = TestString ?? throw new ArgumentNullException();
}
```

For a reason or another, I didn't include this pondering in the original question if there's maybe a shorter way. :)

<edit: The .NET 6 `ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(obj)` could be handy here (or ThrowHelper).

Comment: The code in your gist is different.

Comment: I could be wrong here, but I thought if you enable nullable in your project, and you honor the compiler warnings, then putting null in there would not happen, and it would be safe to assume TestString is NOT null because you trust the value. If you want to accept a null you would want to have `string?` instead of just `string`.

Comment: @TravisWhidden I worded unprecicely, I think, but I'm wondering which would be the cleanest way of doing this. Without resorting to reading the specification on how this is defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to handle checks during inline assignment, as you've already discovered in your gist.

One possibility is to call an extension method to wrap any behavior.

```
public record Test(string TestString)
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is one way to get a comment on record properties. Are there others?
    /// </summary>
    public string TestString { get; init; } = ValidationExtensions.Validate(TestString);
}

public static class ValidationExtensions
{
    public static string Validate(string input)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
            throw new NullReferenceException();
        
        return input;
    }
}
```

This will correctly throw during initialization of the record:

```
var x = new Test(null);
```

Comment: Heh, the other commenter left a note the code was different as it had  a piece with `??`, null coalescing, because I was revolving around this idea but was thinking is this the way to add comments and do checking. Maybe a `ThrowHelper` or private static checkers are optiosn too to someone, I'll add here for later readers. :) Thanks for taking the trouble to make this clear example!